# xunit:Get test method name in ClassData's class

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

This is my sample test,

```
    [Theory]
    [BeforeAfterMethod]
    [ClassData(typeof(GetTestData))]
    public void Test3(int a)
    {
        ReporterLogs.Pass("value of a: " + a);
        //TODO
    }
```

And my GetTestData class is,

```
 public class GetTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
  {
    private string _currentTestMethodName;
    private List<object[]> _data = new List<object[]>();

    public GetTestData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(**Print test method name here**);
        _data.Add(new object[] { 10 } });
    }

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

I want to print the current test(i.e. **Test3** in this case) method name inside GetTestData class. How it can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you try using reflection get type?!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using DataAttribute in Xunit as follows,

```
public class GetTestData : DataAttribute
{
    private List<object[]> _data = new List<object[]>();

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        if (testMethod == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException(testMethod.Name);

        _data.Add(new object[] { 10 });
        return _data;
    }
```

}